# Google Analytics - Setting 'ga' cookie domain to '.www.example.com'

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

This is how the cookie domain is usually set in Google Analytics's tracking code. I understand `auto` and `none` are the other two options.

`ga('create', 'UA-45015643-1', 'example.com');`

The above code, which is a part of Universal Tracking code, sets the cookie domain to `.example.com`.

[image: Cookies when viewd in EditThisCookie chrome extension]

Setting cookie domain to `.example.com` makes cookie accessible to all of its subdomains. But I have set up a cookie-free domain `http://static.example.com` to download static contents and I don't want cookies to be sent along with this type of static resource request. So, I tried this:

`ga('create', 'UA-45015643-1', 'www.example.com');`

This resulted the cookie domain to be set to `.www.example.com`. The tracking was working fine after this update (I used Realtime view to verify), apparently.

But I want to be sure if this actually have no side effects or is not a bad practice.

Comment: Can you clarify the question... its not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GA recommends you set the cookie to the TLD (`example.com`) so that if you go from let's say `www.example.com` to `cart.example.com` or `secure.example.com` in the checkout process, your visitors would still share the main `example.com` cookie.

If this isn't a concern for you, then you can use the `www.example.com` configuration above without consequence.

Comment: Yeah. I don't have any subdomains in my current project. But what if sobdomains don't share the `example.com` cookie? Will there be any effect on analytics data?

Comment: If they don't share the same cookie, they're counted as (n) visits/visitors as they hit each (n) domains - each domain generates a new cookie & unique ID.